# Disable SSL Trusted Peer requirement in specific express router

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, tls1.2

I'm a newbie to NodeJS(Any JS). I'm trying to develop an app which has multiple routers. Here are my router paths.

```
var app = express();
var apiRouter = express.Router();
var adminRouter = express.Router();
var pageRouter = express.Router();

app.use('/api', apiRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use('/', pageRouter);
```

`apiRouter` serve the rest api which will consume in mobile apps. 
`adminRouter` serves the admin dash board. 
`pageRouter` serves the end users as a landing page and some highlights of the app.

I have implemented SSL Peer implementation as below.

```
options = {
  key: // Path to key file, 
  ca: // Path to CA crt file, 
  cert: // Path to crt file, 
  requestCert: true, 
  rejectUnauthorized: true
};
```

How ever I need to remove SSL trusted peer implementation from pageRouter as end user do not have my certification and key. So how can I disable the SSL trusted peer implementation on `pageRouter` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't know what path a client is making a request for until its TLS session has already been negotiated. By that point, it's too late to reject a connection for lacking a client certificate.

Consider putting the API endpoints which require a client certificate on a separate subdomain, or a different port.

Comment: Thanks for the response.